# How to run .vtt and .srt files with videos using QuickTime Player

Tags: quicktime, subtitle

Is there anyway I can run .vtt "WEBVTT" subtitles files and .srt files with QuickTime Player.

I am running QuickTime version 10.5.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of.

In case you're unfamiliar, [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) is a free alternative that has excellent support for subtitles, etc.